# Python sum over map over list

Tags: python

From Mathematica I am used to summing over a map over a list with a very short and concise syntax. E.g. to sum a map over a polynomial function:

```
myList = {1,2,3};
output = Sum[ x^3+x^2+x , { x, myList } ]
```

To do the same thing in Python, I came up with the following syntax:

```
myList = [1,2,3]
output = sum(list(map(lambda x: x*x*x+x*x+x , myList)))
```

My question is: Is that the most simple/efficient way of doing this? I mean, it seems to me that there should be a simpler way than nesting three or four built in functions for such a simple task.

Comment: You don't need `list`, it's wastefully creating a list in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `map` or `list`, you can just `sum` using a generator expression

```
>>> myList = [1,2,3]
>>> sum(x**3 + x**2 + x for x in myList)
56
```

Comment: This is probably the most concise expression.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `list`.  Just:

```
myList = [1,2,3]
output = sum(map(lambda x: x**3 + x**2 + x , myList))
```

Also, the power expression is double asterisk `**`